# Is there an Eclipse shortcut to remove all unused variables?

Tags: java, eclipse

After refactoring test classes, i found myself dealing with a lot of unused variables used by the refactored code.

Having to delete them one by one is tricky, considering doing it too fast will accidentally remove real variables that are used in the code. And also, this could involve lots of files.

I wonder whether the shortcut in Eclipse IDE to remove all unused classes in open editor exists ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'Source > Clean Up...' to remove unused local variables and private members.

Yout will have to configure a custom profile to do this. You can do this in the Clean Up dialog or in the 'Java > Code Style > Clean Up' page in the Preferences. Removing unused variables is on the 'Unnecessary Code' tab of the profile.

You can also do the same thing automatically when a file is saved using the 'save actions' configured on the 'Java > Editor > Save Actions' page of the Preferences.